# C socket, first thread connected close the remaining

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, synchronization

A client can connect contemporary to n couples of servers.
As soon as the first of these is successful, it must send a signal to all the others, to close the remaining threads that are trying to connect.
Shound I use joinables threads to do this? If yes, at least conceptually, how should I proceed?

Thanks to all

Comment: How do you open a socket? Can that mechanism be asynchronous? Can you interrupt it?

Comment: Which threading library are you using?

Comment: C, pthread and socket, sorry!
The mechanism can be asynch and can be interrupted

Comment: No problem, please think about adding these pieces of information to your question.

Comment: What constitutes success here? Is it just establishing a TCP connection? Or is there some negotiation and higher-level functions that need to take place?

Comment: after a connection, the server sends a string to a client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider a situation where n resources are requested, and the first one obtained cancels all the other requests. In your specific situation, resources are socket connections.

If the resources can be requested asynchronously ([future/promise](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)), then there must be a protocol to

- either *check* regularly on the status of the request (polling), or *receive* a notification of the completion (handler) of that request, and
- possibly  cancel the request

In that model, you only need one thread to launch all the requests and poll/wait for notifications. Once one or more resources are acquired, select one of them, close the others, and cancel all the remaining demands (if cancellation is not possible, simply release each extra resource at notification time, or dedicate an extra thread to poll on them and release when received).

In case where the resource request command is synchronous (a blocking socket `connect` call), you will need indeed `n` concurrent threads, each calling the blocking function. At return time, each of them should check on a flag indicating whether another thread has obtained his resource first. If it is not the case, the thread position the flag and carry on. Otherwise, the thread release the resource.
The flag must be atomic, or mutex protected.

As an analogy, imagine a race between n contestants: they all start one after the other, and there's a flag they must capture to be allowed to continue. In order to do so, they must go in a room which only allow 1 person at a time (the mutex), but first they have to get a number (connect to a server). Once a contestant succeeded at getting a number, she goes in front of the door and try to enter the room (hold the mutex). If nobody's inside, she enters (or she waits until the room is empty), and check if the flag is still there (`flag == 0`). If it is, she takes it (`flag = 1;`), and proceed. Otherwise, she must give back her number and exit the race (close connection and exit).

The thread task is basically as follow:

```
void task(address){
    int socket = connect(address);
    If (!check_flag()){
        proceed(socket);
    } else {
        close(socket);
    }
}
```

Where `proceed` is the remaining of the work with the socket.
The `check_flag` function is explained below.

Using *pthreads*, you have `pthread_mutex` to implement it.  If the machine [memory model](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering) allows it, you may also use a simple `volatile` integer, but it is clearly non portable.

Fundamentally, only one function is needed to handle the flag. The pseudo code would look like this:

```
int flag;

int check_flag(){
    int result=0;
    lock();
    result = flag;
    flag = 1;
    unlock(); 
    return result;
}
```

It returns whether the flag is already set, and set it as well.

I should add that [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) provides optional support for [atomic variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). See your OS C compiler documentation.

Comment: Now i'll try synchronous method. since as you said, managing the flag with a mutex, I can understand if I already got a request for it, right?
PS: i must use ansi c89!

Comment: I personally don't have any practical experience of c11, but I felt it was worth being mentioned. And yes, by protecting the flag with a mutex, you should be able to implement a well behaving flag.

Comment: Where can I send my code that I tried to do? The problem is that only the first thread try to connect...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eCMVgu5a 
to testing, I started 3 nc processes: 
nc-l 3000 
nc-l 4000 
nc-l 5000

Comment: Normally, we're supposed to put the code on this site, in the questions and answers. You almost have it, but you need to change things a little.

Comment: Yes of course! I tried to execute your code but this is the output:

` $ ./clientDownload 127.0.0.1 3000 127.0.0.1 2000 127.0.0.1 4000
connect() failed, Err: 88 
connect() failed, Err: 88 
connect() failed, Err: 9 `

` I another 3 terminals i have put in listening these 3 ports:
nc -l 2000
nc -l 3000
nc -l 4000 `

Comment: I did not test my code, I merely wanted to show you what I had in mind. Let me check that.

Comment: Ok, the only missing bit is a c&p of the socket creation code fragment from `main` to `runTask` (not the `setsockopt` part). Btw, I don't know what you are planning to do with your server socket. Anyway, I got it to work as I expected it with that change.